# left Join old syntax migration

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have to migrate an old SQL Statement to SQLServer2008. The old SQL-Statement still has the old Join-Operator "*=". Of course I could set the DB-Compatibility, but I don't like to do this :-)

My Question: I am not sure if I am doing following correct and I can't test the old statement anymore. Could someone please check the syntax of my new SQL-Statement ?

old original statement :

```
select * from A,B where A.field *= B.field
```

My guess:

```
SELECT * from A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.field=B.field;
```

Or is it the opposit way ? :

```
SELECT * from B
LEFT JOIN A
ON B.field=A.field;
```

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * from A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.field=B.field;
```

This is Correct one

Comment: Thank you very much. Only a question to be sure. And it is not an 'left OUTER join' ? What was the old syntax for a 'Left outer join' ?

Comment: Left outer JOIN is now LEFT JOIN thats it

Answer (score 3):

Your first guess is correct. This query:

```
select * from A,B where A.field *= B.field
```

and this query:

```
SELECT * from A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.field=B.field;
```

Produce the same results - provided that the original query was well-behaved with other predicates in the `WHERE` clause - the whole reason why the old syntax is deprecated is that it could produce "interesting" results in some cases - so if you were relying on those, you won't get them.

Answer (score 0):

Both will be equivalent but

```
SELECT * from A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.field=B.field;
```

will be more acceptable.

Comment: You do realise that in the second example, the more important part is that `B` is the `LEFT` table rather than `A`, don't you, and so they are *not* equivalent.